Does Android Framework store allocated appwidget ids consistently?
I have 6 widgets is homescreen, 3 widgets in page1 and 3 widgets in page2. I have performed a factory restore. After the system is up, with AppWidgetHost:allocateAppWidgetId() 6 ids are allocated- 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8. The system is rebooted. After system is up, getAppWidgetIds() method returned the widget ids as expected- 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8. In this power cycle, no widget was added/removed from Homescreen.
After another reboot, getAppWidgetIds() method returned the widget ids as- 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29. these ids were never allocated by the system. The interesting point is- the new ids are already linked with the widget providers. For example- in the previous power cycle, Audio widget was linked with widget id-2. In this power cycle the Audio widget is linked with id-24.
After that I tried multiple reboots. We always got the same list of ids- 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29. Also there was no fatal exception which would kill the application.
Why did AppWidgetHost return the widget ids which were never allocated? How to fix this behavior?

Are you building a widget host? If not, why are you concerned about the id? As far as I could tell it shouldn't change unless the widget was deleted and recreated

@JensV, Yes, on startUp the AppWidgetHost is created as a singleton instance. In this case, the widget id was not deleted or recreated. But still we got some new widget ids. This is seen only once in multiple trials. But I wanted to understand the reason behind it.
On start up, I retrieve the widget ids from AppwidgetHost and set the model data. I don't store widget id in shared preference. Only widget provider and slot id are stored.
